# Material UI select component doesn't show the selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select component and I can see the menu items and also select them but the component doesn't show the selected value. It's handle function works well becauese when I selected an item the the value in the database is updated

Here is the code part from it:

```
handleSelect(event){
        this.props.handleChange(event);
    }

render() {

    const values= {
        "1": translation.getText("SAMEWINDOW"),
        "2": translation.getText("NEWWINDOW"),
        "3": translation.getText("NEWTAB")
    };

    return(

        <Select
            name="code"
            value={values[this.props.data.code]}
            onChange={this.handleSelect}
        >
            {Object.keys(values).map((item) => (
                <MenuItem value={item}>{values[item]}</MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
    )
}
```

I tried to change the object keys type from string to number, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Your are sending the value to the component.

Create a state variable and update the state when value is changed.

Ex - `const [value, setValue] = useState("");`

then in the handleSelect update state such as

```
handleSelect(e) {
     setValue(e);
}
```

finally, on the select component send the updated value

```
<select
     name="code"
     value={values[this.props.data.code]}
     menuItem = {value}
     onChange={this.handleSelect} />
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the code it seems that you are using class components,
So try to define a state which can store the selected value so that you may display that,

```
state = {
  selected: null
}

handleSelect(event) {
  this.props.handleChange(event);
  this.setState({ selected: event });
}

render() {

  const values= {
    "1": translation.getText("SAMEWINDOW"),
    "2": translation.getText("NEWWINDOW"),
    "3": translation.getText("NEWTAB")
  };

  return (
    <Select
      name="code"
      value={values[this.props.data.code]}
      menuItem={this.state.selected}
      onChange={this.handleSelect}
    >
      {Object.keys(values).map((item) => (
        <MenuItem value={item}>{values[item]}</MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

You may refer the select box demo using mui with class component from here,
https://codesandbox.io/s/425lm2479?file=/demo.js